# Camera 2 API Video Recording - Auto flash not working

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2

I have implemented a custom camera that records a video using camera2 API. There is an option to set flash to "On", "off", and "Auto". **Setting flash to "Auto" is not working** while other options are working fine.

Here is the code :

```
    private void updateFlash() {
            Log.e(TAG, "Flash = " + currentFlash);
            switch (currentFlash) {
                case Constants.FLASH_OFF:
                    previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE,
                            CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    break;
                case Constants.FLASH_ON:
                    previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE,
                            CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    break;
                case Constants.FLASH_TORCH:
                    previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE,
                            CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    break;
                case Constants.FLASH_AUTO:
                    previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);

                    break;
            }
 cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequestBuilder.build(),
                        null, null);
}
```

I have googled alot and tried almost all the stackoverflow answers for auto flash but none worked.

Please Help. I do not understand what is the issue.

Comment: Can you please try setting flash mode OFF as well in your auto flash case.

Comment: Tried it.. Not working for video...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14855668/6761707 try this.

Comment: @Sahil That question has nothing to do with the auto flash.. plus its for the old camera API..

Comment: Hi imDroid, did you figure this out? Running into the same issue myself

Comment: No luck.. seems like auto flash only works while taking pictures not while recording a video. Hence to make it work with video recording, one need to add some custom logic here.

Answer (score 0):

I tricked! I wrote a ‍`CaptureCallback` and in `onCaptureCompleted` callback, I get `AE_STATE` and if `AE_STATE` is equal to `CONTROL_AE_STATE_FLASH_REQUIRED` then I turn on flash manually. This solution did not work for some devices such as Samsung J7 or Samsung A5. on devices Where `AE_STATE` returns null this solution wont work. HALF A LOAF is better than no bread. :)

```
 private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallback
        = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                   @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                   @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
        if (previewFlashMode == FLASH_AUTO) {
            Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
            if (aeState != null) {
                if (currentPreviewFlashMode != FLASH_ON && aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_FLASH_REQUIRED) {
                    setFlashMode(captureRequestBuilder, FLASH_ON);
                    setRepeatingRequestAfterSetFlash();
                }
            }
        }

    }

};
```

You should add the callback to `setRepeatingRequest`.